# How to trigger methods on my custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that I'm using in my templates. It does a bit of DOM work for me. I would like the host view/controller that I'm using the directive in to be able to run methods on my directive (and it's controller). But I'm not sure how best to call into the directives scope.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dihedral/6FxrC/2/)

My view code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h3>Test App</h3>
        <button ng-click="scopeClear()">Parent Clear</button>
        <div my-directive string="myString"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the custom directive:

```
angular.module('components', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.string = "";

        scope.$watch(attrs.string, function(value) {
            scope.string = value;
        });
    }

    return {
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.string = "Hello";
            }
            $scope.clear = function() {
                $scope.string = "";
            }
        },
        template:
            "<button ng-click='reset()'>Directive Reset</button>" +
            "<button ng-click='clear()'>Directive Clear</button><br/>" +
            "<input type='text' ng-model='string'>",
        link: link
    }
});
```

And controller:

```
angular.module('app', ['components']).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myString = "Hello";

    $scope.scopeClear = function() {
        // How do I get this to call the clear() method on myDirective
    }
});
```

The workaround I found is jQuery('#my_directive').scope().myMethod(); But this seems wrong, like I'm missing some better part of angular to do this.

It also seems like and $emit isn't right here since I want a targeted method so it won't trigger on additional instances of the directive I have on the same page.

How would I access the directives methods from my parent controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your objective here, and it's possible you could find a better pattern completely.  Typically, directives display the state of the scope which is either an isolate scope (if they are self-sufficient) or a shared scope.  Since you are not creating an isolate scope then they inherit the scope from the controller.  If they are displaying data inherited from the controller then you don't want your controller calling into the directive, rather the directive will simply "redraw" itself whenever the properties in the controller change.

If you, instead, are looking to recalculate some stuff in your directives based on events from outside the directive you don't want any tight coupling - especially if building an entirely separate module.  In that case, you might simply want to use $broadcast from the $scope within MainCtrl to broadcast an event that you may care about, and then your directive can provide the $on('eventName') handler.  This way it's portable to any controller/scope that will fire such an event.

If you find yourself needing to know the exact properties in the controller or the exact functions within the directive then I would suggest that you have too-tightly coupled these pieces and they don't belong in separate modules since they could never be reused.  Angular directives and controllers are not objects with functions, but objects that create scope and update frequently via $digest calls whenever properties in that scope change.  So you may be able to find a way to better model the data, objects, and properties you are displaying.  But I can't say without greater context.

Comment: My directive is like a form element. If I use <div my-directive> to create it, is there no way to get data back out or send methods in without using $emit/$broadcast?

Comment: As you found out there ARE ways of doing it but not great. The point of Angular is to render objects and properties as they are - reactively.  If your directive is displaying the value of a property in your controller then it will automatically display the current value of the property provided it is modified within the digest cycle.  You get into a bunch of hacks, trouble, and head aches when modifying variables outside of angular and then trying to force digests and such.

If your directive is actually a form then you most likely want the advantage of Angular's two-way data binding as well.

Comment: I'm confused about which question I'm trying to ask. If directives aren't very good for building interactive generic components, what in angular should I be looking at?

Comment: I think I'm starting to catch on to making directives useful. If I isolate scope, I can create two-way bindings in and out of the directive, making for much more interactive components (without hacks). Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem! The big mentality switch is models and scopes not functions and dom bindings.  You can also use a shared scope to directly access the scope in your parent controller, if you find yourself doing that.  It's a little less "safe" since your controller could change but it's perfectly valid to do so if the situation calls for it.  Good luck! Angular is a lot of fun.